Prepositions with "Akademie" as a location
Which preposition is used before "der Akademie" when used a location? Specifically, with "lernen". In English it would be "at the academy" or "in the academy"; I don't think it matters which. In German, looking at the DWDS usage database I see "auf" (most common), "an", and "in". But pretty much anything goes if you widen the search to include other verbs.
I know "an" is used with with educational institutions, so to me that makes the most sense. I also know that "auf" is used with some large, institutional buildings, so that might make sense if it's a single building and not a campus. There are examples of both "an" and "auf" in the Star Trek universe, where "the academy" would be taken to mean Starfleet Academy, which has a campus like a university. I suppose "in" might be used if it's a smaller building, but I think if it was that small it would be called a "Schule".
Is there a rule for when to use which preposition, or is it up to preference and habit? And if there is a rule, is there a more general rule?
Full context: In Season 1, Episode 1 of the Series "The Lincoln Lawyer", Lorna Crane is speculating about why so many cops seem to be jerks. She says "Ich glaube, die lernen an der Academy wie man anderen auf den Sack geht." (For what it's worth, "jmdm. auf den Sack gehen" is covered in DWDS. Also, I know it's usually spelled "Akademie" in German, but that's how the subtitles were written.)

"An der Akademie lernen" looks like specifying a location, but it is in fact referring to "Akademie" as an abstract concept of an educational institution.
It does not specify a location related to the campus or building but merely means something like "as a student of the academy".
You can also use "Ich bin auf der Akademie" with a very similar meaning. I, personally, would use "auf" in combination with "sein" rather than with "lernen". (I cannot tell a reason for this. It is my feeling as a native German from Berlin with a university degree. I don't know what all might contribute to this preference. The results from the usage database depend on what you select for Korpus.)
Of course, you can construct various sentence where you refer to a location, e.g. "Ich warte an der Akademie." (I'm waiting at the academy.). In this context it will be understood a location next to a building or next to the entrance.
Other prepositions like "Ich lerne in der Akademie." might get understood as refering to a location, in this case inside a building, rather than referring to the abstract educational institution.

I'm not clear on why you wouldn't use "auf" in combination with "lernen". It's not a combination I would expect but, as I mentioned in the question, it's the most common result in the database search.

@RDBury I updated the answer. I cannot tell a reason or rule for this. The database results are different if you select something else than movie subtitles.

+1. I can subscribe to this also from a POV from ~Hanover

The most common is "lerne auf der Akademie", but on the other hand "lerne in der Schule" is probably used more often than "auf der Schule".
I suspect "in der Schule" stresses the fact that the pupils are actually present inside the building, whereas "auf der Akademie" is a position held as a scholar, not so tightly bound to a location. As a student you are "
auf der Hochschule". People joining a conference are "auf dem Symposium" or "auf der Konferenz".
The preposition "in der Akademie" is used if someone has become a member/laureate of an Akademie, like "er wurde in die Akademie der Künste/ der Wissenschaften aufgenommen."
